# Understanding shell setup script errors

Tags: linux, bash, web2py, sh

I'm trying to run this [web2py install script](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/scripts/setup-web2py-fedora.sh) on a clean CentOS 6 install, and am getting the following set of errors:

```
checkmodule:  loading policy configuration from httpd.te
httpd.te:1:ERROR 'Building a policy module, but no module specification found.
' at token 'EOF' on line 1:

checkmodule:  error(s) encountered while parsing configuration
semodule_package:  Could not open file No such file or directory:  httpd.mod
semodule:  Failed on httpd.pp!

 - Configure Apache to use mod_wsgi

Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/default.conf:
Invalid command 'EOF', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                           [FAILED]

 - Complete!

./setup-web2py-fedora.sh: line 407: EOF: command not found
./setup-web2py-fedora.sh: line 408: EOF: command not found
./setup-web2py-fedora.sh: line 409: EOF: command not found
```

I don't understand why the script is having problems processing 'EOF' as it's just supposed to be the delimiting identifier of a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an erroneous `EOF` at line 182 (the correct one, matching the `<< EOF`, appears at line 193).  This ends up inside the `httpd.te` file, which causes a syntax error when `checkmodule` tries to process it.

Comment: @larsks- thanks i see it now- are lines 228, 300, and 407-9 erroneous too?